# How to pass a list instead of dictionary in python-django to html page

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I want to display the list "response_body" to my html page "home.html"
For that I retrieved id attribute from response_body and the last id which was stored in "id" variable is printed to my html file.

I want to retrieve all the id's and print it to the html page 
I know this will  be done through loop but how?

I am new to django and python any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried printing the last id before the loop ended and I was successful with it but now I want to print all the id'd in the loop.

i tried passing response_body to html instead of context but it gives me an error as response_body is a list type and it asked  me to pass a dictionary variable like context which works fine.

how can I print all the id's in the reponse_body list

home.html

```
<p>results</p>
<p>{{id}}</p>
```

views.py
as this is a fairly long code i am posting just the code which maybe useful.

response_body = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

```
for j in response_body:
    print(j['id'])
    id = j['id']

context = {
    'id': id,
}

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple. Just send the list in a dictionary:

```
context = {
    'ids': [j['id'] for j in response_body],
    'response' : response_body,
    'dict_values': {'a':1, 'b':2}  # a dummy dictonary
}

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

And update the template:

```
<p>results</p>
{% for id in ids %}
    <p>{{id}}</p>
{% endfor %}

<p> Response Body </p>
{% for r in response %}
        {{ r.id }}
        {{ r.description }}
        // and so on
{% endfor %}
<p> dummy dict </p>
{% for key, value in dict_values.items %}
    {{ key }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: works for me, please also tell me if I want to pass one more dictionary to the same home.html file how can I do it?

Comment: one more item in dictionary or one another dictionary? can you please update the question?

Comment: actually both. I actually want  to do this but this doesn't print the description   `context = {
        'ids': [j['id'] for j in response_body],
        'descriptions': [j['description'] for j in response_body],
    }

    return render(request, 'table.html', context)`

Comment: I also want to pass another dictionary as well which will have other things in that for e.g. `return render(request, 'table.html', context, context2)` is it possible? if it is how can I refer it in my html file

Comment: did you iterate through the new list in template, for example like `{% for d in descriptions %}
    <p>{{d}}</p>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: yes I did. It works fine but is there any way I can print both id and description in a single loop? because it prints all the id and then all the description. I want it to be printed as id and then related description along with the id

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look @HassanIkram